# Access - VBA/SQL Recordset loop through not updating

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a code looping through a recordset and I'm trying to update the start date from a varible (JS)  but its not updating... showing an error saying 'Update or UpdateCancel without addNew or edit'

I have put a .edit just after the ourRecordset![Start Date] = JS which is where its failing

```
 Dim ourDatabase As Database
    Dim ourRecordset As Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim ActvJbNum As Long
    Dim RecCnt As Long
    Dim LpRecCnt As Long
    Dim JS As Date
    
    JS = Now()
    ActvJbNum = Me.EntJobNum
    
    strSQL = "SELECT tblRouting.[Job Number], tblRouting.[Start Date], tblRouting.OpDescription, tblRouting.[Op Seq], tblRouting.OpleadTm " & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM tblRouting " & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE (tblRouting.[Job Number])= " & EntJobNum & vbCrLf & _
    "ORDER BY tblRouting.[Op Seq] ASC;"
    
    Set ourDatabase = CurrentDb
    Set ourRecordset = ourDatabase.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    
    
    With ourRecordset
        
        Do Until ourRecordset.EOF
            RecCnt = ourRecordset.RecordCount
            LpRecCnt = LpRecCnt + 1
            ourRecordset![Start Date] = JS
            ourRecordset.Edit
            MsgBox ourRecordset![Start Date] & vbNewLine & ourRecordset![Op Seq] & vbNewLine & LpRecCnt
            
            ourRecordset.MoveNext
            
        Loop
    End With
```

any idea why it's not updating the start date?

Comment: `ourRecordset![Start Date] = JS` <-- What are you trying to do here? Why are you trying to write-back to a (read-only) ADODB Recordset object? Are you trying to update values in your database table? If so then you need to execute an explicit `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Hi Dai, thanks for helping. I'm trying to update the tblRouting.[Start Date] field each time it loops trough. At the moment for testing JS is set to Now() but when working the  dates will be  pulled from the DB. and there's 2 criteria the 1st pass will be different to the rest of the loops. I should be ok with that once i can get it updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Edit` *before* changing the field value.  Afterward, call `Update` to commit the change.

```vb
ourRecordset.Edit
ourRecordset![Start Date] = JS
ourRecordset.Update
```

However, consider doing this with a single SQL `UPDATE`, as the commenters recommended, instead of with a recordset.  Here it is as a parameterized `UPDATE` ...

```vb
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strUpdate As String

strUpdate = "UPDATE tblRouting SET [Start Date] = Now() WHERE [Job Number]=[Which Job]"
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strUpdate)
qdf.Parameters("Which Job") = EntJobNum
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```

Comment: As others have said, use a SQL UPDATE statement.  It will update all of the rows at the same time and prevent deadlocks.

Comment: aghhh.... I was so close...... hrs I've spent trying to work it out,  Thanks HandsUp working now!